# Multiple Classes and IDs

Tags: css, css-selectors

Apologies upfront for basic syntax question. Still learning. My theme default has this:

```css
#main .entry h3 {padding-bottom: 15px;}
```

I have a class of h3 headers  where I want padding-bottom: 0px

I cannot figure out the correct css to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: You need to write a more specific selector.

Answer (score 3):

You need to write a more specific selector than `#main .entry h3`. Assuming the h3 elements in question have a class of "my-class", you can make a more specific rule simply by adding the class name:

```css
#main .entry h3 {padding-bottom: 15px;}
#main .entry h3.my-class {padding-bottom: 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! <pre>#main .entry h3.my-class {padding-bottom: 0;}</pre> worked exactly as I wanted.